# Scoping child and same level classes with Less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to scope my CSS by adding a class to the html-tag. But I also want the other classes added to the html-tag to be included in this scope aswell. In the *style.less* code below you can see what I am trying to achieve using "&" (this doesn't work of course). The reason for doing this instead of doing &.randomClass1 inside the *file.less* is because I don't have the full overview of all the classes that can be added to the html-tag with JS etc.

Is there any workaround for what I am trying to do?

index.html:

```
<html class="scopeClass randomClass1 randomClass2">
```

style.less:

```
.scopeClass,
.scopeClass & {
    @import "file.less";
}
```

file.less:

```
.randomClass1 .foo {}
.foo {}
```

**Desired result:**

```
.scopeClass.randomClass1 .foo {}
.scopeClass .foo {}
```

Comment: Can you not write your file.less like `.randomClass1& { .foo {...} }`? This way if there is a parent it gets appended and if there is none, then nothing is added? The order of classes on the `html` tag doesn't matter.

Comment: I can, but the problem is that there is ALOT more files imported in the actual project I'm working on. I also don't have the full overview of all the classes that is set in the html-tag.

Comment: I don't think it's possible or will ever be possible using native Less syntax. It shoiuld not be hard (if one is familiar with JS) to write a corresponding postprocessing plugin. Alternatively there're a few tools that were developed exactly to solely do that kind of stuff.